# Want to upgrade Intel core 2 duo CPU E7400 @2.8GHz with Windows7

Tags: windows-7, memory, upgrade, intel-core2

Looking to upgrade my PC with below configuration
Processor: Intel core 2 duo CPU E7400 @2.8GHz with Windows7
RAM : 2 GB
System type : 32 bit OS

Can I upgrade the RAM to 8 GB or more? Anything with respect to processor speed.

Thanks,
Mohan

Comment: You have not provided enough information about your system to provide an answer to your question.  Your CPU supports being installed in a system with 8 GB of memory.  You would have to reinstall your operating system in order to support 8 GB of memory, your 32-bit installation, does not support that much memory.  Additionally memory is unlikely to result in any performance increase

Comment: I will reinstall with 64 bit. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could upgrade only if your motherboard supports up to 8 GB of RAM, however, even if you did the 32-bit Windows OS you have installed will only see 4 GB.  In order to see it all, you would need to installed the 64-bit version of the OS.